# Woocomerce configurar un precio para un rol basado en el total del carro

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Un gran saludo para todos, estoy trabajando en una tienda que hay dos roles, cliente y mayorista y necesito que si el mayorista tiene en el carro mas de 50 dolares los precios de los productos se cambien.

Ejemplo:

Producto 1:
Precio Normal: 5 dolares
Precio mayorista si supera los 50 dolares queda en 4 dolares

Producto 2:
Precio Normal: 7 dolares
Precio mayorista si supera los 50 dolares queda en 5 dolares

He probado varios plugins pero ninguno tiene algo cercano,  el precio del distribuidor lo tengo con acf dentro del producto, he buscado una función  o guía que me pueda orientar en esto y no  lo he encontrado.

gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Es necesario que muestres lo que has intentado, tratando de ofrecer un [mcve]. La pregunta tal como está formulada se orienta a pedir opiniones; y ello no se ajusta al formato sel sitio. Por favor entra a [edit] y modifícala teniendo en cuenta las orientaciones que encuentras al las páginas que te sugerí.

Answer (score 0):

al final lo hice a la medida y quedo asi y le puede servir a cualquier persona como base para descuentos automáticos en woocommerce.

Le falta optimizar pero funciona y queda administrable si se utiliza acf.

```
 add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

    function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){   
     // print_r($cart);
         $discount = 0;
         //valor del que se va comparar con el subtotal
         $valorminayorista = get_field( "valorminimo",10 );
         $subtotal =  WC()->cart->subtotal;
         if($subtotal >= $valorminayorista){
              // $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
              foreach($cart->cart_contents as $cart_item ){   
                 $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                  $valuemayorista = get_field( "mayorista",$product_id );   
                  $cantidad = $cart_item['quantity'];   
                  $name = $cart_item['data']->get_title();
                  
                  $discount = $discount + ($valuemayorista * $cantidad );
              }
              $discount =  $subtotal - $discount;
              $cart->add_fee( 'Descuento', -$discount);
         }   
    }
```